# Python - backtracking maze generation recursive function understanding

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, depth-first-search, backtracking

I was looking for ways to create a maze in python.
I came across the code below at [rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze_generation#Python).
I know the code use recursion to build the maze.
I understand the code lines and know what i'm reading and I want to use that code but i'm missing a key understanding of this code.

How exactly dose the recursive function in this code knows when to stop?

```
from random import shuffle, randrange

def make_maze(w = 16, h = 8):
    vis = [[0] * w + [1] for _ in range(h)] + [[1] * (w + 1)]
    ver = [["|  "] * w + ['|'] for _ in range(h)] + [[]]
    hor = [["+--"] * w + ['+'] for _ in range(h + 1)]

    def walk(x, y):
        vis[y][x] = 1

        d = [(x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x + 1, y), (x, y - 1)]
        shuffle(d)
        for (xx, yy) in d:
            if vis[yy][xx]: continue
            if xx == x: hor[max(y, yy)][x] = "+  "
            if yy == y: ver[y][max(x, xx)] = "   "
            walk(xx, yy)

    walk(randrange(w), randrange(h))

    s = ""
    for (a, b) in zip(hor, ver):
        s += ''.join(a + ['\n'] + b + ['\n'])
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(make_maze())
```

Comment: Scroll to the top of the page you cited: `Start at a random cell.
Mark the current cell as visited, and get a list of its neighbors. For each neighbor, starting with a randomly selected neighbor:
If that neighbor hasn't been visited, remove the wall between this cell and that neighbor, and then recurse with that neighbor as the current cell.` - when all neighbours are visited, it stops.

Comment: If you change the dimensions to 2 and 3 and heed [How to debug small programs (#2)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) you can debug its working yourself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applied debug printing to your code:

```
from random import shuffle, randrange

def make_maze(w = 3, h =3):
    vis = [[0] * w + [1] for _ in range(h)] + [[1] * (w + 1)]
    ver = [["|  "] * w + ['|'] for _ in range(h)] + [[]]
    hor = [["+--"] * w + ['+'] for _ in range(h + 1)]

    def debugPrint():
        print("-"*16)
        s = ""
        for (a, b) in zip(hor, ver):
            s += ''.join(a + ['\n'] + b + ['\n'])
        print(s )

        for r in vis:
            print(r) 


    def walk(x, y):
        debugPrint()

        vis[y][x] = 1

        d = [(x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x + 1, y), (x, y - 1)]
        shuffle(d)
        for (xx, yy) in d:
            if vis[yy][xx]: continue
            if xx == x: hor[max(y, yy)][x] = "+  "
            if yy == y: ver[y][max(x, xx)] = "   "

            walk(xx, yy)



    walk(randrange(w), randrange(h))

    s = ""
    for (a, b) in zip(hor, ver):
        s += ''.join(a + ['\n'] + b + ['\n'])
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(make_maze())
```

to visualize whats happening:

```
----------------
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+


[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
----------------
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+  +--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+


[0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
----------------
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+  +--+--+
|     |  |
+--+--+--+


[0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
----------------
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+  +--+--+
|        |
+--+--+--+


[0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
----------------
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+  +--+  +
|        |
+--+--+--+


[0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
----------------
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+  +
|  |  |  |
+  +--+  +
|        |
+--+--+--+


[0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
----------------
+--+--+--+
|  |     |
+--+--+  +
|  |  |  |
+  +--+  +
|        |
+--+--+--+


[0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
----------------
+--+--+--+
|        |
+--+--+  +
|  |  |  |
+  +--+  +
|        |
+--+--+--+


[0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
----------------
+--+--+--+
|        |
+--+  +  +
|  |  |  |
+  +--+  +
|        |
+--+--+--+


[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Final output:

```
+--+--+--+
|        |
+--+  +  +
|  |  |  |
+  +--+  +
|        |
+--+--+--+
```

Comment: I did that but here's my qustion can't i get to a point where i'm surrounded by 1 and i have a 0 somewhere else but not in a neighbor  cell?
I'm probably missing something super obvious here.

Comment: Yes you can, but thats not tragic. On each step all "free ones" are collected into `d = [(x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x + 1, y), (x, y - 1)]` and for each one the recursion is used after shuffling them. If one then has no neighbours and was not visited it will be marked visited by the recursion. If one of them was already visited by some other loop it will ignore it for further maze manipulation.

Comment: @Rxzlion Each cell but the last one will be visited once. the last has only neighbours that were already visited so the `for...` will only ever encounter `continues` in its scoped `if` and never touch the recursion